# SQL script runs fine on one database, errors on another

Tags: sql-server

We have a script that must allow for being re-run several times.

We have an MS-SQL script that updates a table if a (now obsolete) column exists, then deletes the column.  To ensure that the script can be run several times, it first checks for the existence of a column before performing the updates.

The script works as expected on our dev database, updating the data on the first run, then displaying the message 'Not updating' on subsequent runs.

On our test database the script runs fine on the first run, but errors with "Invalid column name 'OldColumn'" on subsequent runs; if I comment out the UPDATE and ALTER statements it runs as expected.

Is there a way to force the script to run even if there's a potential error, or is it something to do with how the database was set-up? (fingers crossed I'm not looking like a complete noob!)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'OldColumn')

    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Updating and removing old column...'
        UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn='X' WHERE OldColumn=1;
        ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN OldColumn;
    END

ELSE
    PRINT 'Not updating'
GO
```

Comment: It's dropping a column and you can't figure out why it's not updating the column you dropped?

Comment: @Randolph - That isn't the OP's question at all. On subsequent runs when the column doesn't exist that code doesn't get executed. They are asking why the non executed code causes a compilation problem in one environment but not another.

Comment: Right, I'm with you. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you could do

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'OldColumn')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Updating and removing old column...'
        EXEC ('UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn=''X'' WHERE OldColumn=1;');
        ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN OldColumn;
    END

ELSE
    PRINT 'Not updating'
```

Comment: exec sp_dbcmptlevel 'dbname' displays 'The current compatibility level is 100.' for both databases

Comment: @cooman - Yes I just began to doubt the answer myself. Compilation of the statement should only be deferred if it refers to a **table** that does not exist. Does the table itself definitely still exist in the dev environment?

Comment: @Martin - the table is definitely there; if I change the update to "UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn='X';" and remove the DROP it correctly displays the 'Not updating' message

Comment: That doesn't mean the table is still there. Compilation would be deferred and you would never actually enter the `if` block if it wasn't. I get the same error as you on my machine unless I wrap it in dynamic SQL so it executes in another batch. This is how it **should** work (ie is documented to work) according to my understanding of it as well. If the table is absolutely definitely there in your **dev** environment would be interesting to know `@@version` for both.

Comment: I've verified the table is there (I also copied the UPDATE into the ELSE to be sure) but now dev and test both error :(  I luckily have other databases to test against, and I've found that changing the compatibility level to 90 reproduces the error, but resetting back to 100 doesn't put it all back as it was... I still get the error.  Perhaps I should just convert to dynamic SQL (which I've tried and works as expected)

Comment: @cooman - I can't explain the behaviour you are seeing where it ever works. Definitely it says here [when you reference an existing table in a stored procedure you cannot list nonexistent columns for that table.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686.aspx) AFAIK that applies to all TSQL batches not just stored procs.

Comment: @Martin - thanks for your efforts on this one; it definitely seems dynamic SQL is the way to go... and now that dev and test are behaving the same it should make it easier to ensure my scripts will work in all environments (I'm running out of databases where the original script still works!)